# Cloned my Anaconda base environment, and now my other environments have lost their names and base environment has changed

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

Here's what my Anaconda environments looked like prior:

```
(base) C:\Users\essoc>conda env list

# conda environments:
#
base                  *  C:\Users\essoc\Anaconda3
dcm_env                  C:\Users\essoc\Anaconda3\envs\dcm_env
george_trading           C:\Users\essoc\Anaconda3\envs\george_trading
george_trading2          C:\Users\essoc\Anaconda3\envs\george_trading2
mcraft                   C:\Users\essoc\Anaconda3\envs\mcraft
pyfinance                C:\Users\essoc\Anaconda3\envs\pyfinance
```

I then ran:

```
(base) C:\Users\essoc>conda create --clone base --name test_base
```

followed by:

```
(test_base) C:\Users\essoc>conda update --all
```

Now my environments look like this (the base environment has changed, and the names of all of my other environments have disappeared):

```
(test_base) C:\Users\essoc>conda env list
# conda environments:
#
                         C:\Users\essoc\Anaconda3
                         C:\Users\essoc\Anaconda3\envs\dcm_env
                         C:\Users\essoc\Anaconda3\envs\george_trading
                         C:\Users\essoc\Anaconda3\envs\george_trading2
                         C:\Users\essoc\Anaconda3\envs\mcraft
                         C:\Users\essoc\Anaconda3\envs\pyfinance
base                  *  C:\Users\essoc\Anaconda3\envs\test_base
```

I simply intended for test_base to be a new environment that was a copy of my base environment. But somehow the "base" environment is now set to the new clone (test_base), and the names of my other environments have all disappeared - meaning I cannot activate them by name. What did I do, and how can I restore the names of my environments and have the base environment as before?

Comment: Can you go to `C:\Users\essoc\Anaconda3\envs` and show me what it looks like

Comment: Here's a screenshot of that folder: https://imgur.com/a/Y18wGvQ

Comment: What happens if you just rename the file test_case and do conda env list

Comment: For anyone with the same issue, solution found here (run deactivate): https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/11074